# Form single Row from all rows with corresponding values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rows

I have dataframe as follows:

```
    2017            2018
    A     B    C    A    B    C
0   12    NaN  NaN  98   NaN  NaN 
1   NaN   23   NaN  NaN  65   NaN
2   NaN   NaN  45   NaN  NaN  43
```

I want to convert this data frame into:

```
    2017            2018
    A     B    C    A    B    C
0   12    23   45   98   65  43
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First back filling missing values and then select first row by double `[]` for one row `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.bfill().iloc[[0]]
#alternative
#df = df.ffill().iloc[-1]]
print (df)
   2017              2018            
      A     B     C     A     B     C
0  12.0  23.0  45.0  98.0  65.0  43.0
```

Comment: what if there is all `NaN` in any columns?

Comment: @abhi1610 - then get `NaN` in this column or columns

Answer (score 0):

One could sum along the columns:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create DataFrame:
tmp = np.hstack((np.diag([12., 23., 42.]), np.diag([98., 65., 43.])))
tmp[tmp == 0] = np.NaN
df = pd.DataFrame(tmp, )

# Sum:
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.sum(axis=0)).T
```

Resulting in:

```
      0     1     2     3     4     5
0  12.0  23.0  42.0  98.0  65.0  43.0
```

This is convenient because [`Dataframe.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas.DataFrame.sum) ignores `NaN` by default. Couple of notes:

- One loses the column names in this approach.
- All-`NaN` columns will return `0` in the result.